# put input type text in an array

Tags: php, html

I have some `text inputs`. The `inputs` are produced from a `while` loop. Now I want put the `values` in an array. Like this:

```
array       values
mark['0']   input1
mark['1']   input2
mark['2']   input3
```

I tried this but not working.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  <form class="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="mark[]"/>
  </form>
}
<form class="form1" name="form1" method="post">
    <button type="submit" name="correction"></submit>
</form>
```

And then

```
if(isset($_POST['correction'])){
$grade=0;   
    $mark=$_POST['mark'];
    foreach($mark as $key =>$value ){
        $grade+=$value;
    }   
print $grade;
}
```

I get these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: mark in C:\xampp\htdocs\virtual_exam\handy_correction.php on line 37

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\virtual_exam\handy_correction.php on line 38
```

The problem may be caused by two forms which arent connected to each other and if YES, how to joined them?
If NO, how to do what i want?

Comment: Got it. It was such a silly question. My brain had been out of working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form to this:

```
<form class="form1" name="form1" method="post">

  <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo '<input type="text" name="mark[]" />';
    }
  ?>

  <input type="submit" name="correction" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And then:

```
if (isset($_POST['correction'])) {
  $grade = 0;   
  $mark  = $_POST['mark'];

  foreach ($mark as $key => $value) {
    $grade += $value;
  }

  echo $grade;
}
```

Comment: WoooW! I dont know why sometimes act like this :|

Answer (score 2):

You should likely have only 1 form element, not one for every row you are trying to output, and certainly not a separate one for the form submission button.

Your problem is that the actual form you are submitting has only one element in it - the submit button.  Thus there are no input fields at all to post.

You should generate your form like this:

```
<form class="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <input type="text" name="mark[]"/>
<?php
}
?>
    <button type="submit" name="correction"></submit>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

What you saying the last paragraph is correct, you are submitting the form1 which contains only the submit button, so `mark` doesn't exist in the PHP script that handles the POST.

so change the HTML to:

```
<form class="form1" name="form1" method="post">
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
    <input type="text" name="mark[]"/>
<?php
}
?>
    <button type="submit" name="correction"></submit>
</form>
```