# PHP $_post select + input for each element

Tags: php

I need to link each value(id) to an amount for making some calculations but I can't figure out how this could work. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<select name="type[]">
<option value="id">...</option>
</select>
<input name="amount"/>

//This repeats with a loop 8 times. There are 8 select boxes with the same options.
```

**PHP**

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];

foreach ($products as $thisProduct) {

    foreach ($id as $value) {
        if ($thisProduct->getId() == $value) {
            $multiply = ($thisProduct->getMultiply($amount));
            array_push($array, $multiply);  
        }

        switch($type){
            case "one":
            $multiplyType = ($thisProduct->getMultiplyType($amount));
            array_push($arrayType, $multiplyType);
            break;

            case "two":
            $multiplyType = ($thisProduct->getMultiplyType($amount));
            array_push($arrayType, $multiplyType);
            break;

            case "three":
            $multiplyType = ($thisProduct->getMultiplyType($amount));
            array_push($arrayType, $multiplyType);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works but the values get multiplied with the last `<input>`. So when the last `input` value = 10, all the values get multiplied by 10. What is the simplest way to link each `input` to a specific `select` element?

Answer (score 0):

Turn your text-input also in to an array. Take a look at this answer for more information: [put input type text in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059067/put-input-type-text-in-an-array)

Comment: Tried it before and added a foreach to iterate through these but didn't work out...